# How to estimate the mean and variance of the minimum of a random set?

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

Given $n$ numbers $x_i,i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, define the set of all possible summation of $x_i$ with different signs:
$$A = \Big\{\Big|\sum_i x_i s_i\Big| : s_i = \pm 1\Big\}$$
and define the minimum of $A$ as $y$.

Now let $x_i$ iid be sampled from the standard Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. It is expected that $y$ will go to zero when $n$ go to infinity. But how to prove it and how to estimate the rate? How to estimate the mean and variance of $y$ (as a random variable)?

Comment: Why should it go to zero? By picking all $s_i$ such that all the values are negative, the sum would approach $- \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Or are you considering the absolute values of the expression, in which case it would go to $0$?

Comment: Thanks for the note. I missed the *absolute value*.